# Postgres-- Restoring table. But table data merging with previous table data

Tags: postgresql

What happens if I do not empty a database before restoring it?

I am facing the following issue:

**Before restoring**:
One table has no primary key and has one row with id 1.

**After restoring**:
After restoring that particular table, it has two rows with id equal to 1.

I don't know reason why this is happening? Might be because of not emptying the database before restoring it.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. It's hard to help because we don't know how your tables are constructed or what code you're trying to run. Editing your question to add your table schema and SQL code will help get useful answers. Please read
[what this site is about](https://serverfault.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
for more tips on writing useful questions that get useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior for this will vary depending upon what sort of data set you are restoring from, and what method you are using to perform the restore. Adding those details will allow for a better answer.

Based on what you've provided though, it sounds like your restore process is doing a simple insert of data, and you don't have a unique constraint on your id column. So there's no reason that Postgres wouldn't allow your ID column to have duplicate values.

If your backup contains the state of the database you want, it's best to drop and recreate the existing database before restoring. It would probably also be good to add a unique constraint on your ID column. If you need it to be unique, this will not only protect you from operational errors like this, but also programming errors in your application.

More information on Postgres constraints: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html